# как запустить асинхронную функцию в телеграмм боте на aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

есть два разных файла, один обновляет json-файл (update_data.py), другой сам бот(bot.py). Как мне вызвать асинхронную функцию из update_data.py в боте, если у него произошла ошибка при открытии json-файла?

update_data.py

```py
import json
import time
import uuid
from datetime import datetime

import aiohttp
import asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


data = {'main': {}, 'times': {}}
times_date = {}
main_data = {}


async def get_data(session, page):
    url_main = 'https://facts.museum'
    headers = {'user-agent': UserAgent().random}

    url = f'{url_main}/from{page}'
    async with session.get(url=url, headers=headers) as r:
        response_text = await r.text()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'lxml')
        blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-lg mb-3 p-0')

        try:
            for element in blocks:
                content = element.find('p', class_='content').text
                title = element.find('img').get('alt')
                link_img = element.find('img').get('src')
                main_data[str(uuid.uuid4())]=[
                    content,
                    title,
                    f'{url_main}{link_img}'
                ]
        except:
            return


async def gather_data():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []

        for page in range(0, 4000, 10):
            task = asyncio.create_task(get_data(session, page))
            tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def main():
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

    while True:
        asyncio.run(gather_data())
        date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        times_date['date']=date
        data['times']=times_date
        data['main']=main_data

        with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

        time.sleep(1800)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

bot.py

```py
import json
import time
from random import choice

from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils import executor
from settings import token


bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)

#keybord
next_fact = InlineKeyboardButton('⏭️ Следующий ⏭️', callback_data='Next')
starting_fact = InlineKeyboardButton(' Запуск ', callback_data='Next')
update_fact = InlineKeyboardButton(' Обновление фактов ', callback_data='Update')

fact_next = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(next_fact)
fact_start = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(starting_fact, update_fact)


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def starting(message: types.Message):
    msg = await message.reply(f'<b>Привет, {message.chat.full_name}!</b>', parse_mode='html')
    time.sleep(2)
    await bot.edit_message_text(
        text='<b><i>Хотите запустить бота?</i></b>', 
        chat_id=message.chat.id, 
        message_id=msg.message_id, 
        parse_mode='html', 
        reply_markup=fact_start)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Next')
async def Next(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    try:
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            fact_key = choice(list(data['main']))
            fact = data['main'][fact_key]
            content = fact[0]
            title = fact[1]
            img = fact[2]
    except:
        msg = await bot.send_message(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
            text='<b><i>[Error] Проблема с файлом.</i></b>', 
            parse_mode='html')  
        time.sleep(4)
        await bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id,
            message_id=msg.message_id,
            text='<b><i>[Restore] Запущен процесс восстановления (~2мин).</i></b>', 
            parse_mode='html')
        await bot.delete_message(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
            message_id=msg.message_id,) 
        #тут должна быть функция по восстановлению файла-json
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            fact_key = choice(list(data['main']))
            fact = data['main'][fact_key]
            content = fact[0]
            title = fact[1]
            img = fact[2]

    await bot.send_photo(
        callback_query.from_user.id,
        photo=img,
        caption=f'<b>{title}</b>\n\n<tg-spoiler><i>{content}</i></tg-spoiler>', 
        parse_mode='html',
        reply_markup=fact_next)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Update')
async def Update(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    try:
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            date = data['times']['date']
    except:
        msg = await bot.send_message(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
            text='<b><i>[Error] Проблема с файлом.</i></b>', 
            parse_mode='html')  
        time.sleep(4)
        await bot.edit_message_text(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id,
            message_id=msg.message_id,
            text='<b><i>[Restore] Запущен процесс восстановления (~2мин).</i></b>', 
            parse_mode='html')
        #тут должна быть функция по восстановлению файла-json
        await bot.delete_message(
            chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
            message_id=msg.message_id,)
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            date = data['times']['date']

    await bot.send_message(
        chat_id=callback_query.from_user.id, 
        text=f'<b><i>Последнее обновление фактов: {date} (GMT +05:00).</i></b>', 
        parse_mode='html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
    except:
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*получилось сделать с помощью метода у класса Dispatcher под названием _loop_create_task*

##### async_update_data.py (code part):

```py
async def start_recoverу():
    date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    await gather_data()
    times_date['date']=date
    data['times']=times_date
    data['main']=main_data

    with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

##### bot.py (code part):

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'Update')
async def Update(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    try:
        with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            date = data['times']['date']
    except Exception:
        dp._loop_create_task(start_recoverу())
```